# Domain registration partnership + availability check

Tags: api, affiliate

I would like to create a simple module for my website that prints keywords and tells the user if the keyword is available to register as domain. Is there any domain name registrar who gives any kind of api to do this? I would like to show something like this:

Keyword | .com domain | .net domain

Website | not available | available - register at XX for $0.99! (<- affiliate link)

[edit] @Anthony Hatzopoulos, @Anagio - I wasn't specific because I don't really care about the form. It can be some kind of widget that just has to be implemented or a raw api that returns data that must be processed before showing it to the user. Raw API without any interface would be the best since you can modify and control outputted data. I do realise however that if there would be any api available people would use it not to generate income for domain registrar, but to use it as free "whois" api operator. I assume that if there exists a domain registrar with such a feature - than it's propably coded in JS to secure the data.

Answer (score 2):

- You can become a enom reseller and use their API: http://www.enom.com/resellers/api-reseller.aspx
- Domai.nr has an interesting API and concept: http://domai.nr/api
- iwantmyname.com will have an API **soon**: http://iwantmyname.com/developer/domain-dns-api
- name.com has a reseller api: http://www.name.com/reseller/
- goddady: http://www.godaddy.com/reseller/domain-reseller-api.aspx

I'm sure a lot of the big registrars have some sort of api for resellers.

You want something like domainhole's namespinner tool http://www.domainhole.com/namespinner/index.php#spinresults

Which if you know how to program you can do with any number of the API's listed.

enom has something similar in their [API docs](http://www.enom.com/APICommandCatalog/index.htm) filed under API Commands > NameSpinner

Comment: He also wants to have an API call which returns available domains with their unique affiliate link already built. I don't believe that would be available in any of their API's.

Comment: I haven't checked all of them but the first one from enom has something called `NameSpinner` (look at docs http://www.enom.com/APICommandCatalog/index.htm). Nothing is going to fit exactly what the original poster requires, there will obviously be coding and design implementation required like usually is required in an API. Otherwise the OP should have asked for a already built 3rd party widget.

Comment: If you don't want to do a little bit of coding work you'll need some turnkey reseller system like http://www.godaddy.com/reseller/domain-reseller.aspx

Comment: That's what I was getting at in his comment to my answer he said `I am looking for a domain name registrar WITH an api or something that would check domains and generate affiliate links` and that makes it seem he wants to do no coding at all and finding a registrar with this built into their API is highly unlikely.

Comment: `I would like to create a simple module` tells me otherwise. Likewise his account on stackoverflow leads me to believe he can code stuffs. @firian you should edit your question to be specific to what you want and are looking for.

Comment: I'm not assuming any skill level in coding but it would clear things up if he edited the question. If he would like to showing something like his diagram that means he needs to code it. API's are returning JSON or XML formats, even if one returned your affiliate ID you'd still have to code the HTML to build the link. Maybe the OP can clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/

JSON and XML output for domain name whois lookups. Automatically queries the right registrar and can handle high volume queries.

Comment: I am looking for a domain name registrar WITH an api or something that would check domains and generate affiliate links. I don't look for api to get whois data only.

Comment: @firian registrars force captchas, unless you're ready to pay for this service which is dirt cheap you really wont find one suitable for your needs. Considering you plan to use affiliate links and earn money you should expect some over head. But if you're expecting a free service which even generates affiliate link automatically you'll never find one. Using the API from the site I gave you, you can program what you want with AJAX once they run a search if it's available display the affiliate link.

Comment: @Anargio I did know about whoisxmlapi - I've also found robowhois.com (which is much cheaper). I am not looking for a free whois lookup api provider, I just want a domain name registrar who will check the domain and return an affiliate link. It can be secured & generated by JS for example to make sure that I won't parse the data after downloading whois info. Maybe someone knows a registrar who offers a functionality like that - I will hope for that and wait.

Comment: @firian is this only for your own use? If so why not use netsol.com where you can search many domains at once. Copy / paste to excel use a simple formula and generate your html source code links then paste them where you need them?